# How to load public ssh key from a file in java?

Tags: java, ssh, rsa

I trying to load public ssh rsa key (id_rsa.pub) from a file:

```
X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(readBytes(keyFile));
return (RSAPublicKey) KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(spec);
```

but I get

> java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException:
>   java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format

How to load this file to RSAPublicKey?

Comment: The code you have is correct, assuming the file is in the correct format.  How did you create the file?

Comment: @maybeWeCouldStealAVan "assuming the file is in the correct format" <-- what is that "correct format"?

Comment: @meybeWeCouldStealAVan, I'm generated key pair with "ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myEmail" -I X.509"

Comment: Hehe, "correct" might not have been the right word to use. "Expected," maybe. I'm looking through an old project now to post a more complete answer.  In short, the output of `return key.getEncoded()` should work, as would the output of openssl when used with certain options, possibly these: http://codeartisan.blogspot.com/2009/05/public-key-cryptography-in-java.html

Comment: `return key.getEncoded()` should be `PublicKey.getEncoded()`

Comment: Thank You, this link is helpful for me.

Answer (score 7):

The x509 encoded data should be in DER format. You can produce such keys using OpenSSL:
(Note, credit to http://codeartisan.blogspot.com/2009/05/public-key-cryptography-in-java.html for the OpenSSL refresher.)

To generate a key, use:

```
$ openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 2048
```

Or, with a passphrase:

```
$ openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private_key.pem 2048
```

Or, using ssh-keygen (following your example):

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myEmail" -I X.509
```

I'll assume you saved the key as 'private_key.pem'
Generate a public key in DER format:

```
$ openssl rsa -in private_key.pem -pubout -outform DER -out tst_public.der
```

A byte array containing the contents of the file will now be accepted by X509EncodedKeySpec.

If you want to load the private key, use OpenSSL to save an *unencrypted* copy of your private key (don't do this in an insecure environment):

```
$ openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in private_key.pem -out private_key.der -nocrypt


You can then pass this file as a byte array to `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`.
```

You can also generate your key pairs in Java:

```
private static int rsabits = 2048; // or higher, if you've got the cpu*time
public static SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom(); // reseed periodically 

public static KeyPair newKeyPair() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    generator.initialize(rsabits, sr);
    return generator.generateKeyPair();
}
```

Then you can use `KeyPair.getPublic()` and `KeyPair.getPrivate()` to access your keys. You can save or load them as byte arrays with something like:

```
public static byte[] pubKeyToBytes(PublicKey key){
    return key.getEncoded(); // X509 for a public key
}
public static byte[] privKeyToBytes(PrivateKey key){
    return key.getEncoded(); // PKCS8 for a private key
}
public static PublicKey bytesToPubKey(byte[] bytes) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException{
    return KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(bytes));
}
public static PrivateKey bytesToPrivKey(byte[] bytes) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException{
    return KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(bytes));
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, and +1 to the author of the blog post as well.

Comment: All of this is correct, but none of it answers the question. The question isn't about how to create a key in Java that can be loaded in Java. It's about using Java to load an existing key created from the ssh command line.

Comment: And the codeartisan link that starts this post would probably be useful if you were trying to load a key stored in a different format, but that also doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Or, use my small library: [openssh-java](https://github.com/fommil/openssh-java). :-)

Comment: That link is broken. Do you have an updated link?